# How do I know that enamelled wire is actually conducting the current?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, magnet

I am trying to make an electromagnet so I bought magnet wire to wrap around an iron core. I am pretty sure that there is a current running through the copper wire because I attached an alligator clip to one end of the wire and in the process and created a gap and saw sparks. I also tried burning with a lighter the insulator and scraping that part off. I attached the ends of my multimeter to check current and it is showing a very small voltage, like ~100 mV, though my power supply is 9V. I checked to see if my electromagnet is magnetic and just weak and it is not working. I tried using a potentiometer to put current instead of voltage and I got nothing. I am really confused and could use some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `it is showing a very small voltage, like ~100 mV, though my power supply is 9V` smells like the power supply goes into short-circuit protection. Try to measure the winding resistance with your DMM.

Comment: You may well have damaged your potentiometer by essentially shorting a 9V battery through it, if it was turned almost all the way down in resistance.

Comment: It seemed to function the same. What are the signs of a damaged potentiometer?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional 19th century method is to get a compass.  Away from your apparatus, it will point to magnetic north.  Any magnetic field will deflect the needle.

But your iron core may already be slightly magnetized.  A compass should be sensitive enough to detect a current in a wire, even without (or away from) the iron core.

If your 9V supply is only putting out 100mV, then the chances are you have successfully short circuited it by connecting a bit of copper wire straight across the terminals.  Electromagnets either need a high current at low voltage, or lots of turns of wire to increase the resistance.

Comment: I'm sorry if this an extra dumb question, this is my first dive into electronics, but how would I know for certain if my battery is shorted? I checked voltage values for the two I had at my desk (i forgot which one I was using) and one measured 8.79v and the other 9.57v . Based on another stack exchange thread it seems like the 8.79 one discharged due to the short circuit but I just want to confirm.

Comment: You know it's shorted when the voltage collapses to (almost) 0V.  An electromagnet is essentially only a bit of copper wire coiled up.  Unless it's a very long thin bit of copper wire, its resistance will be very low.

Comment: @VivekRamadhar An electromagnet basically *is* a short circuit, it's just a useful one. That's why electromagnets are made from long and thin wires - to make a very "long" short circuit. If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, that sort of makes sense. Thanks for the help!